# Hosting Controls over Multiple Threads in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, controls

I have a problem and after three days I still can not find a answer.

I am creating a usercontrol. This control has two controls hosted on it. One is an edit field and the other is a margin that will hold line numbers and other user added stuff.

What I am trying to do is instantiate these to separate controls in their own threads and perform all tasks on these threads eg painting and updating. The usercontrol thread will simply filter messages and direct same to the correct control. I will be doing this by overriding the WndProc method.

Doing all the message stuff I am fine with however how do I instantiate the controls. Once the thread that creates these controls finishes wont the threads die and the controls became inaccessible. Sorry no code at the moment, I tend to do a lot of research before any coding but I can't seem to find anything that can be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to work very well. All UI elements (forms, controls, etc.) have thread affinity requirements that dictate that they can only ever be accessed from the thread that created them. Trying to embed a control hosted on one thread in another control from another thread is an effort in futility. Even if you can get it work (and use the term "work" loosely here) the results may be unpredictable at best. You need to rethink your approach. It would be *much* better to host all of the controls on the same thread and then shuttle off any time consuming operations to a worker thread. Remember, keep the worker thread busy with non-UI related operations only. Once the operation is complete then you can marshal over the results to the UI thread where it can dispatched appropriately to the controls.

Comment: Thanks Brian, what I'm tring to do is have both controls painted in seprate threads so they get painted at the same time (I know "same time" when talking about threading is often incorrect but I think I can explain it this way.). I want to this for performance and fun.